# Missing Return Statement Error Basic Program

Tags: java

Im writing a small program for a class at school and have run into the "missing return statement error." Ive tried googling the error to see if I can find a generic answer that might help me but nothing Ive done to my code has been able to get rid of this error so that my program can compile. For reference, here is the assignment for the program I am trying to write:

You have been commissioned by the US Navy to develop a system for tracking the amount of fuel consumed by fleets of ships. Each ship has a name (ex: "USS Montana"), fuel capacity (the maximum amount of fuel the ship can carry), and amount of fuel currently onboard. In this problem, fuel is measured in "units" and the capacity of each ship is an integer number (ex: The carrier's capacity is 125 fuel units). Each fleet has exactly four ships in it. When a fleet is deployed, each ship in the fleet is deployed. When a ship is deployed, it consumes half of the fuel it has onboard. When a fleet is refueled, each ship in the fleet is refueled. When a ship is refueled, it is totally filled up (its onboard amount equals its capacity)

And here is my code:

```
/**
 * Navy Ship Descriptions
 * 
 * @author Elizabeth Rehbein
 * @version 01/28/16
 */
public class Ship
{

    // instance variables 
    private String name;        //ship name
    private double fuelCapacity;       //ship fuel capacity
    private double fuelCurrent;  //the ship's current fuel on ship after deployments
    private double fuelConsumed;   //the amount of fuel a ship has consumed after deployments


    //constructor
    public Ship(String startName, double startFuelCapacity, double startFuelCurrent, double startFuelConsumed)
    {
        // initialise instance variables
        name=startName;
        fuelCapacity=startFuelCapacity;
        fuelCurrent=startFuelCurrent;
        fuelConsumed=startFuelConsumed;
    }

   //get methods
    public String getName()
    {
        return name;    //returns the name of the ship being called
    }

    public double getFuelCapacity()
    {
        return fuelCapacity;    //the ship's fuel tank capacity
    }

    public double getFuelCurrent()
    {
        return fuelCurrent; //returns the fuel a ship currently has before being refilled
    }

    public double getFuelConsumed()
    {
        return fuelConsumed;               //returns the fuel consumed by a ship
    }

    public void deploy()
    {
        fuelCurrent = fuelCurrent/2;     //reduces ships current fuel by half with every depolyment
        fuelConsumed += fuelCapacity/2;  //adds the fuel used in depolyment to fuelConsumed to track total fuel used
    }

    public double reFuel()
    //refueling each ship returns it to its full fuel capacity
    {
        fuelCurrent = fuelCapacity;
    }   
}




/**
 * A fleet of Navy ships.
 * 
 * @author Elizabeth Rehbein 
 * @version 02/05/16
 */
public class Fleet
{
    // instance variables 
    private Ship ship1;     //ship1 in the fleet
    private Ship ship2;     //ship2 in the fleet
    private Ship ship3;     //ship3 in the fleet
    private Ship ship4;     //ship4 in the fleet

    //constructor
    public Fleet(Ship inShip1, Ship inShip2, Ship inShip3, Ship inShip4)
    {
        ship1=inShip1;
        ship2=inShip2;
        ship3=inShip3;
        ship4=inShip4;
    }


    //deploys the ships
    public void deploy()
    {
        ship1.deploy();
        ship2.deploy();
        ship3.deploy();
        ship4.deploy();
    }

    //refuels the ships after deployment
    public void reFuel()
    {
        ship1.reFuel();
        ship2.reFuel();
        ship3.reFuel();
        ship4.reFuel();
    }

    //prints out the fuel consumed for each ship in the fleet
    public double printSummary()
    //prints out fuelConsumed for each ship
    {
    System.out.println(ship1.getName() +" 's total fuel consumption is " + ship1.getFuelConsumed());
    System.out.println(ship2.getName() +" 's total fuel consumption is " + ship2.getFuelConsumed());
    System.out.println(ship3.getName() +" 's total fuel consumption is " + ship3.getFuelConsumed());
    System.out.println(ship3.getName() +" 's total fuel consumption is " + ship4.getFuelConsumed());
   }
}

/**
 * Driver for Outlab2.
 */
public class Driver
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        //Creating 4 instances of Ship
        Ship ship1 = new Ship("Carrier", 150);
        Ship ship2 = new Ship("Anti-Submarine", 35);
        Ship ship3 = new Ship("Patrol", 22);
        Ship ship4 = new Ship("Destroyer", 83);

        //Creating instance of Fleet
        Fleet fleet1 = new Fleet(ship1, ship2, ship3, ship4);

        //Deploying the fleet twice
        fleet1.deploy();
        fleet1.deploy();

        //Refuel the fleet once
        fleet1.reFuel();

        //Print summary
        fleet1.printSummary();
    }
}
```

Also, I am not supposed to alter the driver for this assignment.

Let me know your thoughts about where I may have gone wrong.
Cheers!

Comment: Do you have a return statement where it shows the error? If not: why not? And why does it expect one? Answer these questions and you have your problem.

Comment: add full error message and indicate in your code at which line you get it

Comment: Any 'method' that is declared as a specific Object data type must "return" a value whether or not you use that value in your code. Essentially, when you declare a method such as:  public double reFuel() it is indicating that the method reFuel() is to return a double data type value.

Answer (score 3):

here:

```
public double reFuel()
    //refueling each ship returns it to its full fuel capacity
    {
        fuelCurrent = fuelCapacity;
    }
```

and here:

```
//prints out the fuel consumed for each ship in the fleet
    public double printSummary()
    //prints out fuelConsumed for each ship
    {
    System.out.println(ship1.getName() +" 's total fuel consumption is " + ship1.getFuelConsumed());
    System.out.println(ship2.getName() +" 's total fuel consumption is " + ship2.getFuelConsumed());
    System.out.println(ship3.getName() +" 's total fuel consumption is " + ship3.getFuelConsumed());
    System.out.println(ship3.getName() +" 's total fuel consumption is " + ship4.getFuelConsumed());
   }
```

You have two methods, you have said that they will return `double` but in their body there is no `return A_DOUBE`. fix them with adding `return statement` or just make them `void` depends on your problem.

Answer (score 2):

`return` statement missing here:

```
public double reFuel()
//refueling each ship returns it to its full fuel capacity
{
    fuelCurrent = fuelCapacity;
    // add return fuelCurrent here;
}
```

---

Missing `return` statement here as well : by looking at the content, this does not require any return statement. make it `void`.

```
public double printSummary()
//prints out fuelConsumed for each ship
{
    System.out.println(ship1.getName() +" 's total fuel consumption is " + ship1.getFuelConsumed());
    System.out.println(ship2.getName() +" 's total fuel consumption is " + ship2.getFuelConsumed());
    System.out.println(ship3.getName() +" 's total fuel consumption is " + ship3.getFuelConsumed());
    System.out.println(ship3.getName() +" 's total fuel consumption is " + ship4.getFuelConsumed());
}
```

---

Also this definition for constructor is having four parameters but you are not passing all the argument in the object constructor in the `main()` method.

```
public Ship(String startName, double startFuelCapacity, double startFuelCurrent, double startFuelConsumed)
{
    // initialise instance variables
    name=startName;
    fuelCapacity=startFuelCapacity;
    fuelCurrent=startFuelCurrent;
    fuelConsumed=startFuelConsumed;
}

    // more errors here: pass all the four arguments.
    Ship ship1 = new Ship("Carrier", 150);
    Ship ship2 = new Ship("Anti-Submarine", 35);
    Ship ship3 = new Ship("Patrol", 22);
    Ship ship4 = new Ship("Destroyer", 83);
```

Answer (score 1):

This method should return a double. If you dont want to return anything, replace double to void.

```
public double reFuel()
//refueling each ship returns it to its full fuel capacity
{
    fuelCurrent = fuelCapacity;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The culprit is

```
public double printSummary()
//prints out fuelConsumed for each ship
{
System.out.println(ship1.getName() +" 's total fuel consumption is " + ship1.getFuelConsumed());
System.out.println(ship2.getName() +" 's total fuel consumption is " + ship2.getFuelConsumed());
System.out.println(ship3.getName() +" 's total fuel consumption is " + ship3.getFuelConsumed());
System.out.println(ship3.getName() +" 's total fuel consumption is " + ship4.getFuelConsumed()); }

 public double reFuel()
//refueling each ship returns it to its full fuel capacity
{
    fuelCurrent = fuelCapacity;
}
```

Return statement in this function is missing.

Either change the return value to `void` or return a `double`.

Comment: Okay great. After reading everyone's comments I have fixed the problem and can hopefully move on to correcting the rest of the program. Thanks for all the help! Cheers!